# How produce labels from desired matrix MATLAB

Tags: matlab, label

I have a matrix as below:

```
    0 1 0 0 0
    1 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 1 0
    1 0 0 0 0
    0 1 0 0 0
    ...
```

Could you please provide a simple matlab code to obtain a label column for above matrix as follows?

```
2
1
4
2
.
.
.
```

Comment: [so] is not a free coding service. If you want someone to do the work for you try http://freelancer.com

Comment: label column means? you want locations of '1' in each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use max() function

[C,I] = max(A) finds the indices of the maximum values of A, and returns them in output vector I.

If there are several identical maximum values, the index of the first one found is returned.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, but how we can write it for whole the matrix?

Comment: I did it but it does not work, I want to have the index of each 1 in each row separately in a column..

Comment: [C,I] = max(A); A=[I;A]; or A=[I,A] either one will work

Comment: does not work... it add a row to matrix A. I want to have a label for each row, for example label for row 0 1 0 0 is 2 and label for 1 0 0 0 is 1, and label of 0 0 0 1 is 4 so finally we will have a column contains 2,1,4

Comment: does not work... it adds a row to matrix A. But I want to have a label for each row, for example label for row 0 1 0 0 is 2 and label for 1 0 0 0 is 1, and label of 0 0 0 1 is 4 so finally we will have a column contains 2,1,4

Comment: then do [C,I] = max(A'); A=[I';A]; or A=[I',A] see dimensions and do